# Setting video.currentTime in componentDidMount with Reactjs (HTML5 Video Element) not working in Safari?

Tags: reactjs, safari, html5-video

I am using reactjs with the flux architecture to run a html5 video.  I store the users currentTime in my database so when they come back to the page the user has the option to resume or restart the video.  I was setting the videos's currentTime with this.video.currentTime in componentDidMount.  This seems to work beautifully except in Safari!!!!  Am I doing something wrong?  the video is give a refs in accordance to the following instructions https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Here is where I reference my video in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    if (this.video !== null) {
        this.video.currentTime = this.props.persistedCurrentTime;
        this.video.addEventListener('ended', this.handleOnEnded);
    }
},
```

In the render I do a refs on the video which is why i'm using this.video above.  Here is the render of this component:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <video
            ref={function(ref) { this.video = ref }.bind(this)}
            controls={false}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            onPlay={this.handleOnPlay}
            onPause={this.handleOnPause}
            onTimeUpdate={this.handleTimeUpdate}
            onVolumeChange={this.handleVolumeChange}
            onMute={this.handleMute}
            id="video">
            <source src={this.props.src} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    );
}
```

To try and better understand what was happening I used several console.log statements in the componentDidMount.  Here is what I printed:

```
 if (this.video !== null) {
        console.log("this.video = "+this.video)
        console.log("this.props.persistedCurrentTime = "+this.props.persistedCurrentTime)
        console.log("this.video.currentTime = "+this.video.currentTime)
        this.video.currentTime = this.props.persistedCurrentTime;
        console.log("this.video.currentTime = "+this.video.currentTime)
}
```

In the console of Chrome I receive the following feedback:

```
 this.video = [object HTMLVideoElement]
 this.props.persistedCurrentTime = 35
 this.video.currentTime = 0
 this.video.currentTime = 35
```

Which is what I expected to receive, as it progresses the video's currentTime to 35 seconds.

However, in Safari I receive the following:

```
[Log] this.video = [object HTMLVideoElement] (main.js, line 770)
[Log] this.props.persistedCurrentTime = 35 (main.js, line 771)
[Log] this.video.currentTime = 0 (main.js, line 772)
[Log] this.video.currentTime = 0 (main.js, line 774)
```

notice that in the last line the video.currentTime is not 35 seconds :(  WHY!!!!!!  It is clear that the video element has mounted from the first line.  What's even more crazy is that if I do this.video.currentTime = 35 in the console, the video moves to 35 seconds!

In advance, thank you for any advice.